# How did they get this answer for critical value

Tags: statistics

I know how to get a critical value but I am not sure now how to do it when they added "when testing the claim that p = 1/2"....

how did they get the answer for critical value ?

[image]

Comment: I have the impression that it is $\alpha =1$% . If so, you need to find how how many $z$'s , you need to go in either direction of the mean to cover $99$% of the distribution: http://www.mathsisfun.com/data/standard-normal-distribution-table.html

Comment: that is right!...I was looking at the wrong table :(

Comment: why is it not letting me vote up for you ughhh

Comment: I wrote a fuller answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The critical values are the set of $z-$ values {$z_0,-z_0$} that have the property that $\alpha$% of the probability lies in the interval $(z_0, -z_0)$. As an example, if you know the $1-2-3$ rule, a.k.a $68-95-99.7$% rule, you know that the critical values for $\alpha=68$ are {$-1,1$} , the critical values for $\alpha=95$% are {$-2,2$}, etc. You can look up in this table: http://www.mathsisfun.com/data/standard-normal-distribution-table.html , how to get critical values for a given significance level: since you're doing a 2-sided test, just move the cursor to the place where you read the percentile $(1-\alpha)/2$.

Comment: I need someone to vote up, I dont have 15 reps so I can accept the asnwer..thank for taking the time....now I understand it .

Comment: No problem, glad to help.

Comment: will vote up when I have 15 reps this week I hope!

Comment: No problem, Jessica.

Answer (score 1):

It would be good if we could see the entire question, but if it is the Sign-Test, then it make sense to use p = 1/2 because it is either "yes" (assigned a plus) or a "no" (assigned a minus, hence the name of the test) But again, more information about the question would be useful

Comment: that is the entire question :)

Comment: that tells me what the minus and plus sign..but how did they get 2.575 ?? because significance level of 0.01 would be 2.33 so why is it 2.575 ?